# Emulator won't start without internet connection

Tags: android, android-emulator

If I start the Android emulator in Android Studio, and my laptop (Linux) has no internet connection, the emulator doesn't start. A small window opens with a header and a black screen, and that's it. I see the process "qemu-system-x86_64" in System Monitor, but it will not boot the emulator.
There must be a way to run it in circumstances where I don't have internet access?

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: On Android 9, 11 its working fine but on Android 13 I am facing this issue. I check on mac os with the emulators. which Android version emulator you are using ?

Comment: @AshutoshOjha I'm using API 33, but I think it was already a problem with API 32

Comment: Did you try deleting the emulator and creating a new one?

Comment: @PriyanshKedia unfortunately same problem  with a new one